# Compose Imports using run-time defined Contract Name

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, mef

I have an MEF Export like below:

```
public interface IMyInterface { }
public interface IInterfaceData
{
    string[] Data { get; }
}

[Export("MyContractName", typeof(IMyInterface))]
[ExportMetadata("Data", "SomeData", IsMultiple = true)]
public class MyInterfaceClass : IMyInterface  { }
```

Which I then Import using:

```
public class MyClass {

     [ImportMany("MyContractName", typeof(IMyInterface))]
     private IEnumerable<Lazy<IMyInterface, IInterfaceData>> _operations;

     private CompositionContainer _container; 

     private void Compose() {
         var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
         _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
         _container.ComposeParts(this);
     }
 }
```

This works fine. However, I would like to be able to Compose my Imports at Run Time using a contract name based on the currently executing business logic. In other words, I would like to be able import a variable contract name. I can get around this by doing this:

```
 private void Compose() {

      var contractName = "MyContractName";  // note this would be determined at run-time

      var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

      var foundExports = _container.GetExports<IMyInterface, IInterfaceData>(contractName);         
      _operations = foundExports; // set manually
 }
```

I am more than happy to do to this*. However, there is now no reason for the `[ImportMany]` attribute and I can no longer use `ComposeParts()`. I would like to keep things consistent throughout my project (for my sake, and my team's) and would like to be able to rely on MEF Attributes, `Compose()`/`ComposeParts()` or both.

Is there some other way to define the `Import` attributes, such that calling `_container.Compose()` would take into account a run-time defined contract name? Perhaps the Exports need to be changed or there is something else in the MEF framework that is available to me (attribute wise)?

*I am not sure if this is even "correct". even though it *does* work. It just feels sloppy if I'm trying to keep all things somewhat consistent.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by directly using a [`CompositionBatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositionbatch(v=vs.110).aspx) on your container.

```
var batch = new CompositionBatch();

// Add the export to the batch via method or object referebce
batch.AddExport(new Export(name, partFactory));
batch.AddExport(new Export(part.Name, () => part));

// Compose into your CompositionContainer
_container.Compose(batch);

private MyClass PartFactory()
{ 
    // TODO: create the part to export..
}
```

Note that for the `container` object, it is possible to export the container itself using [`CompositionOptions.ExportCompositionService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) during construction, thus allowing

```
[Import] CompositionContainer _container;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how the part factory would work... So basically I'd have to write code to manually create the class? Isn't that countering the whole point of letting mef do it for me? Could you fill in some sample code in that todo block?

Comment: Also the return type of your part factory method is `MyClass` should that not be `IMyInterface` or at least `MyInterfaceClass`?